# What is the difference between image and snapshot in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am looking for details about what is the actual difference between image and snapshot. Let us say, I have an instance running on Redhat OS and Apache webserver. If I create an image and snapshot exactly at the same time. What will be the content of an image compared to the snapshot? Let's assume a snapshot is taken when the instance was shut down.

Comment: The first snapshot of a persistent disk is an image. The logical contents are identical if you are not using secure-boot/vTPM. Subsequent snapshots are differentials that depend upon previous snapshots. The physical implementation within Google Cloud is not published. Images can be exported in several popular virtual disk formats (VMDK, VHDX, etc). Snapshots must first be converted to images before being exported.

Answer (score 2):

Snapshots:

- Reduced cost and faster to create than images
- Easiest way for data backup and disaster recovery
- Smaller size than images as there is no OS
- Differential backups - only contains changed data that are different since last snapshot [[click here]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots)
- Can be created for running disks even while they are attached to running instances
- Create snapshot schedules to automatically backup your data.
- Cost involved if you create snapshot in other location than the source disk
- Snapshot will be encrypted as per disk encryption settings
- Creating instance from snapshot is little slower than creating from images

Images:

- Available across different projects [click here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images)
- Creating image for running machine is not recommended
- Images on GCP are pre-configured operating system, however, you can also create your own custom image
- Good for reusing compute engine instance states with new instances
- You can select encryption management solution during custom image creation